# Getting JNI error if getContentResolver().query() API is used in phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to write a plugin to read sms from the inbox and pass them to my java script using Phone gap 2.6 framework and Android 4.  Below is my plugin code snippet.

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Plugin Called");
     Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
            "date", "body" }, null, null,null);
 }
```

With the above code i am getting error

```
06-09 22:57:17.856: E/dalvikvm(12452): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1
06-09 22:57:17.856: E/dalvikvm(12452): VM aborting
06-09 22:57:17.856: A/libc(12452): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

Is it a permission issue or Phonegap doesn't support querying content resolver?
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Once you will get the cursor value after this .it will work simple as java code structure or Do you need to call other part as well? coursor.movefirst();?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question, finally i figured it out and it turned out to be a permission issue. After adding  to manifest file it started working fine.